# Subtract a date to currentDate() in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My final goal is to create a derived column in Azure Data Factory (in a dataflow), using 2 dates as following.

I would like to subtract a date named `MinWADAT` (in `integer` format, like '20120203') from `currentDate()` (returning for example '2021-10-05'). The result should be in days unit.

I try to use the following function:

`toDate(MinWADAT)-currentDate()`

but the result is an empty column.

Can you help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked whether something like `toInteger( (currentTimestamp() - toTimestamp(MinWADAT, 'yyyyMMdd')) / 86400000 )` is what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried and it's the solution I was looking for (I didn't know this way of calculating). Thank you very much ray !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression of `toInteger( (currentTimestamp() - toTimestamp(MinWADAT, 'yyyyMMdd')) / 86400000 )` to get date difference in day(s).

explanation:

1. compute the difference of 2 dates in timestamp datetype - `<result 1>`
2. divide `<result 1>` by 1000 milliseconds * 60 seconds * 60 minute * 24 hour = 86400000 to get difference in day(s) - `<result 2>`
3. convert `<result 2>` into integer by using toInteger(`<result 2>`)